# what is the necessary css for offset.left

Tags: jquery, css, offset

This page => http://api.jquery.com/offset does not adequately explain the necessary css involved. Neither do any of the 5 or so SO questions I read , related to this subject touch on CSS issues, either.

1) what CSS will cause `$(this).offset.left` to return 'undefined'?

2) It is also necessary to know what other issues will complicate offset.left (eg. will `$("object").hide()` cause offset.left to return undefined? etc)

I need to know what CSS will kill offset.left and what CSS will return a proper value.

THNX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this).offset().left` will always return a value. jQuery is determining this value based upon the box model by which browsers render the elements of the page.

CSS provides a way to control the offset values via a defined language, however once rendered it always has a value.

So the answer to your question (and the reason you have not found the answer you are looking for before) is that jQuery and CSS are both controlling/reading an underlying technology. jQuery **is not** reading CSS rules.

---

If you hide the element then it is no longer part of the box model, and `offset().left` will return a value of 0:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9xaCe/

Comment: depending on what the 'this' is, it can return 'undefined' sometimes. I need to know only what will cause $('someobject').offset.left to be 'undefined'. For example, if $('someobject') has previously been hidden by .hide() then it's offset will be 'undefined' because it is hidden. This is one example. Also, if div#someobject is not position: relative; in the css, jquery can say div#someobject is 'undefined' depending on the situation.

Comment: There is a reason why there are so many questions and problems on SO related to offset.left

Comment: thanks for the DEMO but the problem is you are not initiating the print after it had been hidden here http://jsfiddle.net/5CYUn/

Comment: I see I left out the perenthesis. offset().left not offset.left

Answer (score 1):

The page you referenced says:

> jQuery does not support getting the
>   offset coordinates of hidden elements

If the element is hidden then I guess `.offset` will return `undefined`.  So the answer to your question 2 is yes.

Comment: but that is only one thing that will cause 'undefined' my answer is what are the css and js issues that will cause 'undefined' and what is necessary for offset.left to hold and integer.

Comment: what I really want someone to do is update the jquery wiki on this subject because otherwise we are shooting in the dark. I don't like sitting in front of a css editor turning on and off attributes until something works. The wiki page should explain the types of issues that will cause 'undefined' css or js related.